# Racket ormap in erlang

Tags: erlang, racket

Is there a better way to implement Racket's [ormap](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/map..rkt%29._ormap%29%29) in Erlang than:

```
ormap(_, []) -> false;
ormap(Pred, [H|T]) -> 
    case Pred(H) of 
        false -> ormap(Pred, T);
        _ -> {ok, Pred(H)}
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty good to me. I'm not sure how smart Erlang is about optimizing these things, but you might want to actually bind the non-false pattern match to a variable, and avoid recomputing `Pred(H)`.

```
ormap(_, []) -> false;
ormap(Pred, [H|T]) ->
  case Pred(H) of 
    false -> ormap(Pred, T);
    V -> {ok, V}
  end.
```

The Racket version doesn't include the `ok` symbol, but that seems like the Erlangy thing to do so I don't see anything wrong with it. You might similarly expect Pred to return an attached `ok` symbol for the non-false case, in which case:

```
V -> V
```

or

```
{ok, V} -> {ok, V}
```

should work.